# What does "TypeError:can't modify frozen string" mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I got this error when using the Twitter gem, and passing in an array.

My code looks innocent enough - wondering what is causing this?

```
 def twitter_get_users(client, user_names=[])
    copy=Array.new(user_names)
    users = client.users(user_names)
  end

TypeError: can't modify frozen string
    from gems/twitter-1.0.0/lib/twitter/client/utils.rb:10:in `gsub!'
    from /gems/twitter-1.0.0/lib/twitter/client/utils.rb:10:in `clean_screen_name!'
    from /gems/twitter-1.0.0/lib/twitter/client/utils.rb:33:in `merge_users_into_options!'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby allows you to [freeze objects](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/frameset.html?content=http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/classes.html%23freezingobjects) so that they may not be mutated. Either the Twitter gem froze a string and then tried to call `gsub!` on it, or you passed in an already-frozen string.

*This answer doesn't help you solve the root of your problem, but it does answer the questions of "What does this mean and why is it happening?"*

Comment: thanks! it was interesting how the error was in how the strings got freezed when they were created in the first place. I essentially duped the individual strings, and it worked. =)

Answer (score 3):

Try this and see if it helps:

```
def twitter_get_users(client, user_names=[])
  client.users user_names.map(&:dup)
end
```

Comment: i tried this before and this did not work, but the equivalent of this worked => user_names.map{|u| u.dup} => because the strings in them were frozen! =)

Comment: That's interesting. I updated my answer based on your comment. I think though that there is something funny going on with the `user_names` array you are passing. Perhaps you should use `dup` when the strings are first added to the array (unless there is a reason you need to freeze them).

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you try opening up `gems/twitter-1.0.0/lib/twitter/client/utils.rb` and looking at line 10? :-)
2. if you can't find anything obvious in there, try `grep -r '.freeze'` on your rails project and on that gem's directory (`gems/twitter-1.0.0/`)